# iOS - Logic to Detect iPad / iPhone Device for storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to define my storyboard as part of an Authentication script in my App Delegate file - which is used to pass relevant data to particular views.

All works fine - but by defining my storyboard in this way I overwrite the path for all devices (iPad or iPhone), i'd like my app to be universal and follow different storyboards dependant on device  - therefore ideally I'd like to detect the device and apply the relevant storyboard ID to a variable so the correct storyboard runs and the authentication script still functions properly - but I'm not sure how to do this..

This is my code so far -

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ipad_story" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *controller;
 UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Could the storyboard contain logic to detect the device and either apply ipad_story or ipad_phone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options, use the [iOS device modifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html), `~ipad`, so you will have story like `main_story` for iphone and `main_story~ipad` for iPad.

Or if you need to detect it in code look at the [`UIUserInterfaceIdiom`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW41) :

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad
} else {
    // iPhone
}
```

The first option should be used if possible, the second op option is only need if you have to do it in code.

Comment: Cheers @ rckoenes - this works but displays on an iphone 5 as if constrained to the proportions of a iphone4

Comment: Well you can solve that by setting up autolayout correctly or use Autoresize mask. I never ever had to design a specific UI for 3,5" and 4" devices. Just make the screen adjust to screen size.

Comment: fair enough - cheers for the help and the most comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size, CGSizeMake(640, 1136)))

UIViewController *homeViewController;
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a swift solution:

```
if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {
   //iPad
}
else {
   //iPhone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {    
        //iphone
 }
else
 {
         //iPad
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the right NIB on init, not viewDidLoad.

```
- (id)init

    if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return [self initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerIpad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        return [self initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerIphone5" bundle:nil];
    } 
    else 
    {
        return [self initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this macro

```
#define IS_IPAD     ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = 
    [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

To detect iPad/iPhone :

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];

    } else {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
```

Comment: It this you should use the device modifier on the file `~ipad` and `~iphone`.