# iOS 8 Storyboard / Main Interface

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode6

I'm creating an iOS 8 app. I have two storyboards for iPhone and iPad.
The iPad.storyboard is set to be the main interface.
My problem is that every time I run on iPhone device, the iPad.storyboard is still being called.

Is there a way to automatically detect the storyboard for a certain device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306597/ios-logic-to-detect-ipad-iphone-device-for-storyboard

Comment: I'm using Swift. The thread you've given is for iOS 7. Thanks.

Comment: I see. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26269486/388280

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you are looking for a swift solution
   if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {
       //iPad
      var iPadBoard: UIStoryboard!
      iPadBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)
      let viewcontroller : UIViewController = iPadBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("iPad") as UIViewController
      self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
    }
    else {
       //iPhone
      var iPhoneBoard: UIStoryboard!
      iPhoneBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPhone", bundle: nil)
      let viewcontroller : UIViewController = iPhoneBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("iPhone5") as UIViewController
      self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
    }
```

Comment: But, my concern is that even I run on iPhone, the design that is being called is from iPad.storyboard not the iPhone.storyboard. To make this clear, is there a way to set the Main Interface programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: then you can load different storyboard. see above.

Answer (score 0):

To get the iOS to automatically choose for you, name the storyboards with ~iphone and ~ipad at the end (after the name and before the extension.)

For example:
   main~iphone.storyboard
   main~ipad.storyboard

Note that "iphone" and "ipad" must be lower case.  If you name them with mixed case, they will work on the simulator but not the device because the Mac's default formatting is case-insensitive, but the iOS format is case-sensitive.

Comment: I've tried to rename my storyboards to main~iphone.storyboard and main~ipad.storyboard but nothing happens.